# SQL Stored procedure combining data from two rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am just after the best method to implement the following functionality.

Basically, I am querying a table and I want to fetch data from two different rows.

To explain a bit better :

Let's say Table 'myTable' has 3 columns 'StudentID', 'StudentName', 'StudentPercentage'.

I pass student ID as a parameter to a stored procedure which should return back the student's rank, along with the name and student id of the student whose rank is first.

To calculate rank, I use -

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StudentPercentage DESC) AS Rank`

So, if the parameter(Student ID) passed to the stored procedure is '1', the data is something like this (First Rank's student details + details of the student whose student ID was passed as an argument) :

```
StudentID  StudentName  StudentPercentage Rank
   5           A             96            1
   1           C             84            6
```

The data that I want to return back is :

**A** (First rank's student name), **96** (first rank's student percentage), **6** (rank of the student whose ID was passed as an argument).

I am unable to figure out a way to get the desired results.

Any help would be great!

Thanks.

P.S. - The code that I am writing is in C# connecting to SQL database. Though here, all I want to see is how this data can be returned by the stored procedure. In short, focussing on the SQL query.

Comment: "6 (rank of the student whose ID was passed as an argument). " should'nt there be 1 instead of six.

Comment: Q: Have you written any code so far?  Q: Is your question about writing a stored procedure, or coding a stored procedure for this particular problem?  Q: What language will you call the stored procedure and process the results from?  T-SQL?  C#?  Something else?  If you can post any code, that would be enormously helpful.  Thank you in advance :)

Comment: @Zohaib, no, it should return 6(rank of the student whose ID was passed as an argument), along with first rank student's name and percentage.

Comment: @paulsm4, the question is regarding coding the stored procedure. SQL is the language. I am yet trying to figure out the way to write the query for this one..:|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something along the lines of:

```
Select Top(1) StudentName,
  StudentPercentage,
  (YOUR RANKING SELECTION CODE HERE AS A SUBQUERY Where StudentId = @StudentId) as Rank
From myTable
Order By StudentPercentage Desc
```

Just use a subquery.

Comment: Upon re-reading into your question, I mistakenly made the assumption you were referring to the "first ranked student" as the one with the highest StudentPercentage. Please disregard my answer.

Comment: Worked! Not sure if this is the best approach or not, but at least it got me what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Select the first student then get the passed in student with a correlated sub query.

Something like:

```
select
x.StudentName, x.StudentPercentage,
(select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StudentPercentage DESC) AS Rank where studentID=@myStudentID)
from
(
select StudentName, StudentPercentage,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StudentPercentage DESC) AS Rank
)x 
where x.Rank=1
```

You should probably use RANK() not ROW_NUMBER so you handle ties.

Comment: GCaiazzo suggested 2 selects over 3, and that worked. How is Rank() better than row_number()?

Comment: Because ROW_NUMBER = 1 does not work when you have 2 students with the same percentage.  You'll just get one (at random).  RANK will give them both the value 1 hence return you both.
That's why I have 3 selects - becuase you can't put ROW_NUMBER() in the where.  The other way is to do a subquery on MAX(percentage) in your where clause, but it's still another select.  I would worry about correctness first and how many statements there are second.

Comment: You are right. Sorry, since this was just an example and not exactly what I am working on, I didn't pay much heed to the scenario that I had mentioned in the question. My bad.